# why did google create the webm format?

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, mkv

I known the WebM format is derived from Matroska format. And WebM is a subset of Matroska. But why Google didn't use Matroska directly?

What advantages does WebM have over Matroska?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifies the player code and communicates intent. Matroska has support for hundreds of codecs. Webm has support for just a handful. Because browsers only support a limited set of codes, you can have confidence that a modern browser can play a webm. But who knows if it can support the codec in a random matroska file.